# How can I migrate this SQL Server trigger from T-SQL to PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

The following works on SQL Server but I could not translate it to PL/SQL

PL/SQL:

```
create or replace TRIGGER CHANGE_TRIGGER
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON test
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF INSERTING THEN
        INSERT INTO test_LOG
           SELECT :NEW.* , SYSDATE, USER, 'I' FROM DUAL;
      END IF;
END;
```

Original SQL Server trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_LOG_TEST] ON [dbo].[TEST]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
DECLARE @lg_name VARCHAR(128)
SELECT
@lg_name = login_name,
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE session_id = @@SPID
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [TEST_LOG]
SELECT *, GETDATE(), @lg_name ,'I' from deleted
END
```

Comment: I don't think you can reference an entire row with the ```:NEW```bind variable. It will work if you reference the individual columns. 
```INSERT INTO test_log (col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES (:NEW.column1,SYSDATE,USER,'I');```
Check the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-217E8B13-29EF-45F3-8D0F-2384F9F1D231, there are plenty of examples in there.

Comment: I want to write a trigger but this trigger get only a table name

Comment: how I can write please help me

Comment: In Oracle, you're going to have to explicitly list out the column names as @KoenLostrie suggests.  I'm not sure what you mean by a trigger getting a table name since triggers don't take parameters.  Maybe you are saying that you have code that generates the trigger dynamically based on the table name?  In which case, you'd need to query the data dictionary to get the list of columns in the table so that you could list the out in the trigger you generate.

Comment: One key difference of PL/SQL and T-SQL triggers: in T-SQL you work with recordsets and your trigger is called once per transaction, while in PL/SQL you work with one record and your trigger is called once per row. This means that you should not have to `SELECT` anything in the trigger if it's a basic audit trigger. Just reference each column individually as said above--it's tedious so you can script the trigger creation. Avoid use of `*` as it is brittle--tables don't always have matching column order between environments, so such constructs are risky--always use explicit column names.

Comment: Yes, I want a dynamic table