# How to make :NEW dynamic PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

This is my trigger code. But I want to dynamically reference `:new` attributes without writing them one by one. How can I do that?

```
create or replace TRIGGER test_CHANGE_TRIGGER
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON test
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING THEN
      INSERT INTO test_LOG 
      VALUES (:NEW.d, :NEW.s, :NEW.n, :NEW.v, :NEW.e, SYSDATE, USER, 'I');
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: As stated in the comments to your previous question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58098750/how-can-i-migrate-this-sql-server-trigger-from-t-sql-to-pl-sql , you cannot reference the entire row in a pl/sql trigger. If you don't want to write them one by one you could generate a pl/sql block that generates the trigger code or just the insert statement. See answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a sql statement to generate the insert statement for you. Copy the result and paste it in the trigger code. 
Example for table emp:

```
SELECT 
'INSERT INTO emp_log(empno,ename, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno, log_date, user, operation) VALUES ('||
':NEW.'||LISTAGG(column_name,' ,:NEW.') WITHIN GROUP(order by column_id)||',SYSDATE,USER,''I'')' 
 FROM user_tab_columns 
WHERE table_name = 'EMP';
```

This will return

```
INSERT INTO emp_log(empno,ename, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno, log_date, user, operation) VALUES (:NEW.EMPNO ,:NEW.ENAME ,:NEW.JOB ,:NEW.MGR ,:NEW.HIREDATE ,:NEW.SAL ,:NEW.COMM ,:NEW.DEPTNO,SYSDATE,USER,'I')
```

Comment: I will try and make  comeback

Comment: That's what I want, but it comes in one colon.

Comment: Please be more specific. What does "it comes in one colon" mean ? We cannot see your screen: give us as much information as possible.

Comment: The query you type must also have a total of 11 columns, but when I run the query it returns as a single column.

Comment: ________________________________________________________________
| INSERT INTO test_LOG VALUES ('||':NEW.'||LISTAGG(column_name,' ,:NEW.') WITHIN GROUP(order by column_id)||',SYSDATE,USER,''I'',USER)                    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|INSERT INTO test_LOG VALUES (:NEW.,SYSDATE,USER,'I',USER)                 |

Comment: You misunderstood the point. I wrote a select statement that generates a query statement. The output of that select statement is the insert statement that you can use in your trigger code. So if you want a trigger on table "test" you would run that query in sql or sqldeveloper then copy the output of the query in the trigger body as "INSERT INTO_TEST_LOG..." statement

Answer (score 0):

Lucky you, the answer is pretty straightforward: you can't do that, and you have to name all values one-by-one.

Unfortunately, there's nothing (provided by Oracle) you could use for that purpose.

Though, you could try to create your own procedure which would use dynamic SQL and create triggers for you (query `user_tab_columns` to get list of all columns). Dynamic SQL doesn't scale well, is difficult to debug, but - if you think that it'll help (because there are hundreds of triggers you have to create) - go for it.